# What do you think?

Tags: visual, steganography

There is a message encrypted here somewhere, can you figure it out?

[image: puzzle]

Please ignore the zeros as they are just filling the gap.

Transcription:

```
119 103 115  90  55  98  51 102  66 100  74  71 108  51 116  70  83  47  78  97  74  83  90  49  89  43  65
113 115  56  57  82 101  49 119  54 104  55  48  82  72 121  54  80 119 120  65 103  50  65  98  84  55  57
118  54  88 115  82 112  77  80 103 107  98 101  73  73 122 105  82 118  85 107 113  47 107  48  66  49  89
 68  71  72  71 109 120 104  86  81  87 107 110 113  67 115  90  83  53  74  65  52  89 105 121  67  50  79
 43 118  87  73  65  74  76 107  56  75  77  73  51  70  84 114 112  84  67  90 118  77  97  54  72 114  84
 97  77 118 117  50  80  75 105 110  82 107  87 120 118  86  73 116  51  82  49  97  71  78  54  86  65  69
114  56 113  98 104 104  47 108  55 101  57  53  54  80 101 122 104  98  43  79  67  65 107  72 112 105  83
 86  71  43  72 101 114  87  52 108  50  82  54  77 100  57 114  67  74  71  81  88  72  71 117  88  98  43
 86 115  65  72  56 104  87  52  72  87 110  48  69 114  98  49  49  68  53  51 110  85  83 104 116  43  55
 79  50  82  54 114  57 117 110  97  48  98  79  71 110  51  74  49  50  75  66  54  51  82 118  69  75  49
 71 102  86 111  71  89 117  84  74  81  71  99  85 112  90  97  66 104  51  85 103 110  75  84  67 121  85
 52 106  43 111  57  49 117  98  97  77 120  77 114  53  81  71  76  78  56  65 110 121  88 110 104 120  68
 89 102 105 109  79  98 113  47  49 108 112 107  72  76  76 112  57  89  86 105  56  85 111  73  66 112  84
101  90  74 106  67  83  80  48  99 118  65  88 110  82 103 106  49  87  52  47  70 103  82  80  50 101 112
 84  97  76  49  71 116  51  85 115 107  47  79  85  84  43  50 121  77  57  75  68  87  55 122 115 109  66
105 118 117  75  57  77  73  77  79  83  69  85 110  66  80  56  89  90 114 118  51 122 118  73 102  70  90
 49 102  48  79  66 107  77  99  85  50  78  85 100 111 106 103  56 104  47  47  97 120 121  81 102  56 106
 89 105 114 101 105  77 115  79 108 115 105  86  97 118  71  77 113  49  75  81  82  48 122 107 104  90  80
118 102 111  76  76  66  43 113 111  57 116  52  98  81  76  78  84  81 119  56  99 122  70 117  68  55 106
 72 112 112 119  85  55  89  84  81  99 111  83 107 120  65 117  55  57  49  80 115 103 102  72  52 117 110
 56 107  69  73 103  99  72  82  69  79  55  56  80  53 104  49  85  49  99 115  48  74 121  57  87  71  51
 90 107  78 120 108  57  66  70 114  76  98  56  97 108 110  74  99 117  65 112  78 113 105  48  55 112 101
 74 113  84 114 120  54  53  84 120 104  99 116  73  70  71  67 117 114  88  75  56  74  81 121  97  77 102
117  69 121 109  57 117 100  78 117 104 106  78 110  80 107  90  89 115  79 119  43  47  69 114 101  48  84
112  70  88  47  68 121  74  84 109  65  67  85  77  90 112  68  87  54 109  48 100 117 112  66 114  57  51
 52  56  89 113  73  79  83  47  76  83 108  47 114 113  89  99 112  83 111  80 115 109  50  97 118  99  67
 67 115  56  65  47  99  82 112 111  78 117  65 103 102  50 118 103 118  85  75 118  86  67 113 112  87  54
109  89 115  75  99 109 109 122  99  99 122 106  55  73  49 117 102 100 113 104  81  71  48  51  79 107  87
121 105  89  43  87  56  88 110 102 116  90 115  80  43  83  49  56  65 114  68  82  90  83 105 108 112  54
 48  87  69 120 120 110 118 100 122 117 122  72  85  48 103  82  99 100  77  84  52  56 104 112  53  90 105
 81  56  87  87  73  76 122  90 103 113 102 104  56  71 106  51 121 121  98  66 113 100  74 104 101 114  66
120  65  74 105 116  76 103  77 107 110 117 108  55  56  86  54 103  61  61   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
114 122  88 116  82  49 116  47 112  87  76 118  43  51  48  74  69  77 106 108  66  81  61  61   0   0   0
116  49 116 102  67  57 116  71 105  98  79 122  98 102 104 113 122 102  73 108  76  81  61  61   0   0   0
```

Tip #1:

> This is encrypted and compressed using popular/simple methods

Tip #2:

> It is encrypted with AES in CBC mode PKCS7 padding, the last two lines are key and initialization vector

Tip #3:

> The encrypted content is DEFLATE-compressed data

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: Also, I am *not* transcribing that. Please provide a transcription or nobody will want to solve this.

Comment: just noticed that, sorry :p

Comment: I'll just point out the obvious and say that the number represents a shade, where 255 is white and 0 is black

Comment: The transcription has `0` at the bottom right instead of `254` (not that it makes any difference), also the last two rows are 24 numbers long, the third last is 19 if that helps anyone

Comment: Mr JonMark Perry edited that "aes" to "as", but the original word was already giving a clue...

Comment: @RômuloGabrielRodrigues You should have the ability to undo an edit.

Comment: the squares get whiter the higher the number they hold?

Comment: yeah, the transcription already give the numbers away to make it a little easier, the zeros and the 254 should be ignored as they're there just to define the gray scale limits as the colors were generated from the actual data and to complete the square

Comment: I thought AES uses 128-bit IVs.  Why is your  IV longer?

Comment: @Rubio in base64 22 characters equals 16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial, might help you

> wgsZ7b3fBdJGl3tFS/NaJSZ1Y+A
>  qs89Re1w6h70RHy6PwxAg2AbT79
>  v6XsRpMPgkbeIIziRvUkq/k0B1Y
>  DGHGmxhVQWknqCsZS5JA4YiyC2O
>  +vWIAJLk8KMI3FTrpTCZvMa6HrT
>  aMvu2PKinRkWxvVIt3R1aGN6VAE
>  r8qbhh/l7e956Pezhb+OCAkHpiS
>  VG+HerW4l2R6Md9rCJGQXHGuXb+
>  VsAH8hW4HWn0Erb11D53nUSht+7
>  O2R6r9una0bOGn3J12KB63RvEK1
>  GfVoGYuTJQGcUpZaBh3UgnKTCyU
>  4j+o91ubaMxMr5QGLN8AnyXnhxD
>  YfimObq/1lpkHLLp9YVi8UoIBpT
>  eZJjCSP0cvAXnRgj1W4/FgRP2ep
>  TaL1Gt3Usk/OUT+2yM9KDW7zsmB
>  ivuK9MIMOSEUnBP8YZrv3zvIfFZ
>  1f0OBkMcU2NUdojg8h//axyQf8j
>  YireiMsOlsiVavGMq1KQR0zkhZP
>  vfoLLB+qo9t4bQLNTQw8czFuD7j
>  HppwU7YTQcoSkxAu791PsgfH4un
>  8kEIgcHREO78P5h1U1cs0Jy9WG3
>  ZkNxl9BFrLb8alnJcuApNqi07pe
>  JqTrx65TxhctIFGCurXK8JQyaMf
>  uEym9udNuhjNnPkZYsOw+/Ere0T
>  pFX/DyJTmACUMZpDW6m0dupBr93
>  48YqIOS/LSl/rqYcpSoPsm2avcC
>  Cs8A/cRpoNuAgf2vgvUKvVCqpW6
>  mYsKcmmzcczj7I1ufdqhQG03OkW
>  yiY+W8XnftZsP+S18ArDRZSilp6
>  0WExxnvdzuzHU0gRcdMT48hp5Zi
>  Q8WWILzZgqfh8Gj3yybBqdJherB
>  xAJitLgMknul78V6g==
>  rzXtR1t/pWLv+30JEMjlBQ==
>  t1tfC9tGibOzbfhqzfIlLQ==
>
>  Using AES+CBC+PKCS7 gives text:
>
> eJztmGGugzAMg6/UbPe/24QeKHXsUGDTHoTlT1un8VcIDGnPloT9xTzDAQTfn1m1RymIxeAiFzENyJZ53RTC6X2Q5NDmYibQ2djrHpDOr8Uw0ZqbQ wrEOhpN8AjkJ3t1BDU90OiJd/0FiMrY7EWRMYay KTkBxjiSMQcr8RhDo1jhnXrUDgKARRzdDvxLBlplYphFtH4hjSLgxJyUvjo4N H5QuA3OFIFkCPT0FM/0ZcH2O9yF8QWeH2HsQ2WAsVaKBaLTFZ4UgIMotmT2zDJrh e0QuoRtEDsDxJTOQgLpsg ytRgy3cbhGwtB0DZuGVG3RSFIVg zOddRuYcraQlhHAwS0pXR5kIQ2CZ e5NXQm0M4elaELyPZD2vyKHbJY/i4g8yhhhC0EXW RnG8AZe01ASggW08jy6NCql6vDP3QchnfLvEH6gVyBI0RBIZKXYuXnaVODmQhDLAwso50M4DeE AtGP4rch8paqu7AsqC90FDrRLkjXZwVJL7sWxGKgC0FYRxNQptkPcgiiOih7LL1aDBen2UUg8pf4EEQRUIds GzcCuJTSyBou8j7IGiffGcahacvDjGGkAuawU1nFzwJ1NSDyJAQSsMQIK78ILsgzxdUb3pA

Comment: Yeah, I thought the same thing. I tried doing every third line (since equals signs typically mark the endings of base64-encoded information) but no luck.

Comment: That's the correct first step

Comment: The original question had the intentional typo "aes", so the answer likely involves AES en/decryption. What's the key? The image is named "oC1EV.png" but I'm unsure if that should be used somehow.

Comment: All you need to decrypt is already in the transcription

Comment: @RômuloGabrielRodrigues i guessed AES, but that one does not have "==" at the end. Plus AES has 24 different mods, and I don't even know what text should I put in there and if there is password or not. Plus I don't even know if that is AES or not, so there are thousands of possibilities what you mean with "popular method" and AES is obviously wrong. So far it is too general :/

Comment: That is a AES/CBC/PKCS7 encrypted and the key and IV are at the two last lines. The result of the decryption would give you DEFLATE-compressed data.

Answer (score 2):

From the transcription we have the hex values:

```
77 67 73 5a 37 62 33 66 42 64 4a 47 6c 33 74 46 53 2f 4e 61 4a 53 5a 31 59 2b 41
71 73 38 39 52 65 31 77 36 68 37 30 52 48 79 36 50 77 78 41 67 32 41 62 54 37 39
76 36 58 73 52 70 4d 50 67 6b 62 65 49 49 7a 69 52 76 55 6b 71 2f 6b 30 42 31 59
44 47 48 47 6d 78 68 56 51 57 6b 6e 71 43 73 5a 53 35 4a 41 34 59 69 79 43 32 4f
2b 76 57 49 41 4a 4c 6b 38 4b 4d 49 33 46 54 72 70 54 43 5a 76 4d 61 36 48 72 54
61 4d 76 75 32 50 4b 69 6e 52 6b 57 78 76 56 49 74 33 52 31 61 47 4e 36 56 41 45
72 38 71 62 68 68 2f 6c 37 65 39 35 36 50 65 7a 68 62 2b 4f 43 41 6b 48 70 69 53
56 47 2b 48 65 72 57 34 6c 32 52 36 4d 64 39 72 43 4a 47 51 58 48 47 75 58 62 2b
56 73 41 48 38 68 57 34 48 57 6e 30 45 72 62 31 31 44 35 33 6e 55 53 68 74 2b 37
4f 32 52 36 72 39 75 6e 61 30 62 4f 47 6e 33 4a 31 32 4b 42 36 33 52 76 45 4b 31
47 66 56 6f 47 59 75 54 4a 51 47 63 55 70 5a 61 42 68 33 55 67 6e 4b 54 43 79 55
34 6a 2b 6f 39 31 75 62 61 4d 78 4d 72 35 51 47 4c 4e 38 41 6e 79 58 6e 68 78 44
59 66 69 6d 4f 62 71 2f 31 6c 70 6b 48 4c 4c 70 39 59 56 69 38 55 6f 49 42 70 54
65 5a 4a 6a 43 53 50 30 63 76 41 58 6e 52 67 6a 31 57 34 2f 46 67 52 50 32 65 70
54 61 4c 31 47 74 33 55 73 6b 2f 4f 55 54 2b 32 79 4d 39 4b 44 57 37 7a 73 6d 42
69 76 75 4b 39 4d 49 4d 4f 53 45 55 6e 42 50 38 59 5a 72 76 33 7a 76 49 66 46 5a
31 66 30 4f 42 6b 4d 63 55 32 4e 55 64 6f 6a 67 38 68 2f 2f 61 78 79 51 66 38 6a
59 69 72 65 69 4d 73 4f 6c 73 69 56 61 76 47 4d 71 31 4b 51 52 30 7a 6b 68 5a 50
76 66 6f 4c 4c 42 2b 71 6f 39 74 34 62 51 4c 4e 54 51 77 38 63 7a 46 75 44 37 6a
48 70 70 77 55 37 59 54 51 63 6f 53 6b 78 41 75 37 39 31 50 73 67 66 48 34 75 6e
38 6b 45 49 67 63 48 52 45 4f 37 38 50 35 68 31 55 31 63 73 30 4a 79 39 57 47 33
5a 6b 4e 78 6c 39 42 46 72 4c 62 38 61 6c 6e 4a 63 75 41 70 4e 71 69 30 37 70 65
4a 71 54 72 78 36 35 54 78 68 63 74 49 46 47 43 75 72 58 4b 38 4a 51 79 61 4d 66
75 45 79 6d 39 75 64 4e 75 68 6a 4e 6e 50 6b 5a 59 73 4f 77 2b 2f 45 72 65 30 54
70 46 58 2f 44 79 4a 54 6d 41 43 55 4d 5a 70 44 57 36 6d 30 64 75 70 42 72 39 33
34 38 59 71 49 4f 53 2f 4c 53 6c 2f 72 71 59 63 70 53 6f 50 73 6d 32 61 76 63 43
43 73 38 41 2f 63 52 70 6f 4e 75 41 67 66 32 76 67 76 55 4b 76 56 43 71 70 57 36
6d 59 73 4b 63 6d 6d 7a 63 63 7a 6a 37 49 31 75 66 64 71 68 51 47 30 33 4f 6b 57
79 69 59 2b 57 38 58 6e 66 74 5a 73 50 2b 53 31 38 41 72 44 52 5a 53 69 6c 70 36
30 57 45 78 78 6e 76 64 7a 75 7a 48 55 30 67 52 63 64 4d 54 34 38 68 70 35 5a 69
51 38 57 57 49 4c 7a 5a 67 71 66 68 38 47 6a 33 79 79 62 42 71 64 4a 68 65 72 42
78 41 4a 69 74 4c 67 4d 6b 6e 75 6c 37 38 56 36 67 3d 3d 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
72 7a 58 74 52 31 74 2f 70 57 4c 76 2b 33 30 4a 45 4d 6a 6c 42 51 3d 3d 00 00 00
74 31 74 66 43 39 74 47 69 62 4f 7a 62 66 68 71 7a 66 49 6c 4c 51 3d 3d 00 00 ff
```

This hex values represents encrypted text:

> wgsZ7b3fBdJGl3tFS/NaJSZ1Y+Aqs89Re1w6h70RHy6PwxAg2AbT79v6XsRpMPgkbeIIziRvUkq/k0B1YDGHGmxhVQWknqCsZS5JA4YiyC2O+vWIAJLk8KMI3FTrpTCZvMa6HrTaMvu2PKinRkWxvVIt3R1aGN6VAEr8qbhh/l7e956Pezhb+OCAkHpiSVG+HerW4l2R6Md9rCJGQXHGuXb+VsAH8hW4HWn0Erb11D53nUSht+7O2R6r9una0bOGn3J12KB63RvEK1GfVoGYuTJQGcUpZaBh3UgnKTCyU4j+o91ubaMxMr5QGLN8AnyXnhxDYfimObq/1lpkHLLp9YVi8UoIBpTeZJjCSP0cvAXnRgj1W4/FgRP2epTaL1Gt3Usk/OUT+2yM9KDW7zsmBivuK9MIMOSEUnBP8YZrv3zvIfFZ1f0OBkMcU2NUdojg8h//axyQf8jYireiMsOlsiVavGMq1KQR0zkhZPvfoLLB+qo9t4bQLNTQw8czFuD7jHppwU7YTQcoSkxAu791PsgfH4un8kEIgcHREO78P5h1U1cs0Jy9WG3ZkNxl9BFrLb8alnJcuApNqi07peJqTrx65TxhctIFGCurXK8JQyaMfuEym9udNuhjNnPkZYsOw+/Ere0TpFX/DyJTmACUMZpDW6m0dupBr9348YqIOS/LSl/rqYcpSoPsm2avcCCs8A/cRpoNuAgf2vgvUKvVCqpW6mYsKcmmzcczj7I1ufdqhQG03OkWyiY+W8XnftZsP+S18ArDRZSilp60WExxnvdzuzHU0gRcdMT48hp5ZiQ8WWILzZgqfh8Gj3yybBqdJherBxAJitLgMknul78V6g==rzXtR1t/pWLv+30JEMjlBQ==t1tfC9tGibOzbfhqzfIlLQ==

The text without line breaks can be analyzed to discover more details.

> ! As you may notice the last part has a subtle pattern of `==`, so that represents the end of each base64 part, being content, 128 bit key and 128 bit IV in the same text block, so we can try to decrypt it. As I was trying to hint, it was encrypted with AES, the CBC and PKCS7 part are the rough part to discover as 
>   only CBC uses IV and with other block methods the padding would be wrong, the PKCS7 is a common used padding method and one of a few used with AES by default.

Decrypted:

> 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

And... a little problem:

> The result of decryption can be mistaken when trying to DEFLATE as said in hint, that's because the plus signs can be missed in the decryption. Adding them and decompressing using DEFLATE give us...

this weird data:

> 300000000000000000000000011111110001111000111100011111110001111000000000011100000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000111111100011110001111000111111100011110000000000111000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000001111111000111100011110001111111000111100000000001110000000000000000000000000200011111111111111111000011100000000000111000011111100001110000111111100011100001111111111111111100002000111111111111111110000111000000000001110000111111000011100001111111000111000011111111111111111000020001111111111111111100001110000000000011100001111110000111000011111110001110000111111111111111110000200011111111111111111000011100000000000111000111111100001110000111111100011100001111111111111111100002000111100000000001110000111111100000001111111111000000011111111111111111111000011110000000000111000020001111000000000011100001111111000000011111111110000000111111111111111111110000111100000000001110000200011110000000000111000011111110000000111111111100000001111111111111111111100001111000000000011100002000111100000000001110000111000000011110000000000000000011100001110000111111000011110000000000111000020001111000000000011100001110000000111100000000000000000111000011100001111110000111100000000001110000200011110000000000111000011100000001111000000000000000001110000111000011111100001111000000000011100002000111100000000001110000111100000011110000000000000000011100001110000111111000011110000000000111000020001111000000000011100001111111111111100011110001111111111000000000000001110000111100000000001110000200011110000000000111000011111111111111000111100011111111110000000000000011100001111000000000011100002000111100000000001110000111111111111110001110000111111111100000000000000111000011110000000000111000020001111111111111111100001110000111000011100000000000000000111111111111111110000111111111111111110000200011111111111111111000011100001110000111000000000000000001111111111111111100001111111111111111100002000111111111111111110000111000011100001110000000000000000011111111111111111000011111111111111111000020000000000000000000000001110000111000011100001110000111000111100011110001110000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000011100001110000111000011100011110001111000111100011100000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000111000011100001110000111000111100011110001111000111000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000001110000111000011100001110001111000111100011110001110000000000000000000000000211111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100001111111111000000011111111111111111111111111112111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111000011111111110000000111111111111111111111111111121111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110000111111111100000001111111111111111111111111111200000000000000000111100000000000000000111100000000000001110000111000011100011110000111000111100011112000000000000000001110000000000000000001110000000000000011100001110000111000111100001110000111000111120000000000000000011100000000000000000011100000000000000111000011100001110001111000011100001110001111200000000000000000111000000000000000000111000000000000001110000111000011100001110000111000011100011112111111100000000000001111000111100011110001111111000111100011110000000000000000000000001111000000000021111111000000000000011110001111000111100011111110001111000111100000000000000000000000011110000000000211111110000000000000111100011110001111000111111100011110001111000000000000000000000000111100000000002000000000011110000000000111111100011111110000000111000000011110000111000000000000001110000111111111120000000000111100000000001111111000111111100000001110000000111100011110000000000000011100001111111111200000000001111000000000011111110001111111000000011100000001111000111100000000000000111000011111111112000000000011110000000000111111100011111111000000111000000011110001111000000000000001110000111111111120001111000111100011111111110000000000011111111110000000000111111111110001111111111100000001110000000200011110001111000111111111100000000000111111111100000000001111111111100011111111111000000011100000002000111100011110001111111111000000000001111111111000000000011111111111000111111111110000000111000000021110000000111111100000001110000000111111110000000000111111000000011111111111111000011111110000000111211100000001111111000000011100000001111111000000000011111110000000111111111111110000111111100000011112111000000011111110000000111000000011111110000000000111111100000001111111111111100001111111000000111121110000000111111100000001111000000111111100000000001111111000000001111111111111000011111100000001111211100000001111000111111111111111110000000111100011111110000000000000000000000000000000000011111100002111000000011110001111111111111111100000001111000111111100000000000000000000000000000000000111111000021110000000111100011111111111111111000000011110001111111000000000000000000000000000000000001111110000200011111111111000000000011111110001111111111111111100000001111111111111111111111111111111111111111112000111111111110000000000111111100011111111111111111000000011111111111111111111111111111111111111111120001111111111100000000001111111000111111111111111110000000111111111111111111111111111111111111111111211111111111111000000011100000001110001111100111100011110001111000111111110011110001111000111100011112111111111111110000001111000000011100001110000111000111100011110001111111000111100001110000111000111121111111111111100000011110000000111000011100001110001111000111100011111110001111000011100001110001111211111111111111000000111100000001110000111000011100011110001111000111111100011110000111000011100011112000111111100001110000000111111111100000000000000000000011100000001111111111111111111111111000000111120001111111000011100000001111111111000000000000000000000111000000011111111111111111111111110000001111200011111110000111000000011111111110000000000000000000001110000000111111111111111111111111100000011112000000011100001111111111000000000011110001111111111111100011110000000111000000000000000000111000000020000000111000011111111110000000000111100011111111111111000111100000001110000000000000000001110000000200000001110000111111111100000000001111000111111111111110001111000000011100000000000000000011100000002000000011100001111111111000000000011110001111111111111100011110000000111000000000000000001111000000020001111000111111100000001110000000000011100001110000000000111100011111111111111000000011111110001111200011110001111111000000011100000000000111000011100000000001111000111111111111110000000111111100011112000111100011111110000000111000000000001110000111000000000011110001111111111111100000001111111000111120001111000000111111111110001111111111100000001111110000111111100000000001111111111111100011111111111200011110000000111111111100011111111111000000011111100001111111000000000011111111111111000011111111112000111100000001111111111000111111111110000000111111000011111110000000000111111111111110000111111111120001111000000011111111110000111111111100000001111110000111111100000000000111111111111100001111111111200011111110000111111000000000001111111111111100000011111110000111000000000000000000000111100000011112000111111100001111110000000000011111111111111000000111111100001110000000000000000000001111000000111120001111111000011111100000000000111111111111110000001111111000011100000000000000000000011110000001111211111111111111111111111111100000001111000111111111111110001111000111000011111111111000000000000011112111111111111111111111111111000000011110001111111111111100011110001111000111111111110000000000000111121111111111111111111111111110000000111100011111111111111000111100011110001111111111100000000000001111200000000000000000000000011100001111111111000111110000001111111000000000011110001111000111111111111112000000000000000000000000111000011111111110000111000000011111110000000000111000011110001111111111111120000000000000000000000001110000111111111100001110000000111111100000000001110000111100011111111111111200000000000000000000000011100001111111111000011100000001111111000000000011100001111000111111111111112000111111111111111110000111111100011111110000111000111100011111110000000111111111110000000111111000020001111111111111111100001111111000111111100001110001111000111111100000001111111111100000001111110000200011111111111111111000011111110001111111000011100011110001111111000000011111111111000000011111100002000111111111111111110000111111100011111110000111000111100011111110000000111111111110000000111111000020001111000000000011100001110000000111111100000001111111111000000011110000000000000000011110000001111200011110000000000111000011100000001111111000000011111111110000000111100000000000000000111100000011112000111100000000001110000111000000011111110000000111111111100000000111000000000000000001111000000111120001111000000000011100001110000000111100000001111111111000111100000001110001111111111100001111110000200011110000000000111000011100000001111000000011111111110001111000000011100011111111111000011111100002000111100000000001110000111000000011110000000111111111100011110000000111000111111111110000111111000020001111000000000011100001110000000011100000011111111111000111100000011110000111111111000001111110000200011110000000000111000011100000000000111111111111100000001111000111111100000000000000000011100011112000111100000000001110000111000000000001111111111111000000011110001111111000000000000000000111000111120001111000000000011100001110000000000011111111111110000000111100011111110000000000000000011110001111200011111111111111111000011100000001111111000011111100000001111000111100000011111111000111111100011112000111111111111111110000111000000011111110000111111000000011110001111000000111111110001111111000111120001111111111111111100001110000000111111100001111110000000111100011110000001111111100011111110001111200000000000000000000000011100000001111111000000000000001110000111000011100011111111000111100011111112000000000000000000000000111000000011111110000000000000011100001110000111000111111110001111000111111120000000000000000000000001110000000111111100000000000000111000011100001110001111111100011110001111111200000000000000000000000011100000001111111000000000000001110000111000011100011111111000111100011111113

The data is weird...

> ...because the 2 and 3 digits, it can be noticed that the 3 characters are only in beginning and ending of the text, we can remove it, the 2 characters are evenly distributed, if you replace them for linebreaks you get...

This binary matrix

> 0000000000000000000000001111111000111100011110001111111000111100000000001110000000000000000000000000
>  0000000000000000000000001111111000111100011110001111111000111100000000001110000000000000000000000000
>  0000000000000000000000001111111000111100011110001111111000111100000000001110000000000000000000000000
>  0001111111111111111100001110000000000011100001111110000111000011111110001110000111111111111111110000
>  0001111111111111111100001110000000000011100001111110000111000011111110001110000111111111111111110000
>  0001111111111111111100001110000000000011100001111110000111000011111110001110000111111111111111110000
>  0001111111111111111100001110000000000011100011111110000111000011111110001110000111111111111111110000
>  0001111000000000011100001111111000000011111111110000000111111111111111111110000111100000000001110000
>  0001111000000000011100001111111000000011111111110000000111111111111111111110000111100000000001110000
>  0001111000000000011100001111111000000011111111110000000111111111111111111110000111100000000001110000
>  0001111000000000011100001110000000111100000000000000000111000011100001111110000111100000000001110000
>  0001111000000000011100001110000000111100000000000000000111000011100001111110000111100000000001110000
>  0001111000000000011100001110000000111100000000000000000111000011100001111110000111100000000001110000
>  0001111000000000011100001111000000111100000000000000000111000011100001111110000111100000000001110000
>  0001111000000000011100001111111111111100011110001111111111000000000000001110000111100000000001110000
>  0001111000000000011100001111111111111100011110001111111111000000000000001110000111100000000001110000
>  0001111000000000011100001111111111111100011100001111111111000000000000001110000111100000000001110000
>  0001111111111111111100001110000111000011100000000000000000111111111111111110000111111111111111110000
>  0001111111111111111100001110000111000011100000000000000000111111111111111110000111111111111111110000
>  0001111111111111111100001110000111000011100000000000000000111111111111111110000111111111111111110000
>  0000000000000000000000001110000111000011100001110000111000111100011110001110000000000000000000000000
>  0000000000000000000000001110000111000011100001110001111000111100011110001110000000000000000000000000
>  0000000000000000000000001110000111000011100001110001111000111100011110001110000000000000000000000000
>  0000000000000000000000001110000111000011100001110001111000111100011110001110000000000000000000000000
>  1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110000111111111100000001111111111111111111111111111
>  1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110000111111111100000001111111111111111111111111111
>  1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110000111111111100000001111111111111111111111111111
>  0000000000000000011110000000000000000011110000000000000111000011100001110001111000011100011110001111
>  0000000000000000011100000000000000000011100000000000000111000011100001110001111000011100001110001111
>  0000000000000000011100000000000000000011100000000000000111000011100001110001111000011100001110001111
>  0000000000000000011100000000000000000011100000000000000111000011100001110000111000011100001110001111
>  1111111000000000000011110001111000111100011111110001111000111100000000000000000000000011110000000000
>  1111111000000000000011110001111000111100011111110001111000111100000000000000000000000011110000000000
>  1111111000000000000011110001111000111100011111110001111000111100000000000000000000000011110000000000
>  0000000000111100000000001111111000111111100000001110000000111100001110000000000000011100001111111111
>  0000000000111100000000001111111000111111100000001110000000111100011110000000000000011100001111111111
>  0000000000111100000000001111111000111111100000001110000000111100011110000000000000011100001111111111
>  0000000000111100000000001111111000111111110000001110000000111100011110000000000000011100001111111111
>  0001111000111100011111111110000000000011111111110000000000111111111110001111111111100000001110000000
>  0001111000111100011111111110000000000011111111110000000000111111111110001111111111100000001110000000
>  0001111000111100011111111110000000000011111111110000000000111111111110001111111111100000001110000000
>  1110000000111111100000001110000000111111110000000000111111000000011111111111111000011111110000000111
>  1110000000111111100000001110000000111111100000000001111111000000011111111111111000011111110000001111
>  1110000000111111100000001110000000111111100000000001111111000000011111111111111000011111110000001111
>  1110000000111111100000001111000000111111100000000001111111000000001111111111111000011111100000001111
>  1110000000111100011111111111111111000000011110001111111000000000000000000000000000000000001111110000
>  1110000000111100011111111111111111000000011110001111111000000000000000000000000000000000001111110000
>  1110000000111100011111111111111111000000011110001111111000000000000000000000000000000000001111110000
>  0001111111111100000000001111111000111111111111111110000000111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
>  0001111111111100000000001111111000111111111111111110000000111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
>  0001111111111100000000001111111000111111111111111110000000111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
>  1111111111111100000001110000000111000111110011110001111000111100011111111001111000111100011110001111
>  1111111111111100000011110000000111000011100001110001111000111100011111110001111000011100001110001111
>  1111111111111100000011110000000111000011100001110001111000111100011111110001111000011100001110001111
>  1111111111111100000011110000000111000011100001110001111000111100011111110001111000011100001110001111
>  0001111111000011100000001111111111000000000000000000000111000000011111111111111111111111110000001111
>  0001111111000011100000001111111111000000000000000000000111000000011111111111111111111111110000001111
>  0001111111000011100000001111111111000000000000000000000111000000011111111111111111111111110000001111
>  0000000111000011111111110000000000111100011111111111111000111100000001110000000000000000001110000000
>  0000000111000011111111110000000000111100011111111111111000111100000001110000000000000000001110000000
>  0000000111000011111111110000000000111100011111111111111000111100000001110000000000000000001110000000
>  0000000111000011111111110000000000111100011111111111111000111100000001110000000000000000011110000000
>  0001111000111111100000001110000000000011100001110000000000111100011111111111111000000011111110001111
>  0001111000111111100000001110000000000011100001110000000000111100011111111111111000000011111110001111
>  0001111000111111100000001110000000000011100001110000000000111100011111111111111000000011111110001111
>  0001111000000111111111110001111111111100000001111110000111111100000000001111111111111100011111111111
>  0001111000000011111111110001111111111100000001111110000111111100000000001111111111111100001111111111
>  0001111000000011111111110001111111111100000001111110000111111100000000001111111111111100001111111111
>  0001111000000011111111110000111111111100000001111110000111111100000000000111111111111100001111111111
>  0001111111000011111100000000000111111111111110000001111111000011100000000000000000000011110000001111
>  0001111111000011111100000000000111111111111110000001111111000011100000000000000000000011110000001111
>  0001111111000011111100000000000111111111111110000001111111000011100000000000000000000011110000001111
>  1111111111111111111111111110000000111100011111111111111000111100011100001111111111100000000000001111
>  1111111111111111111111111110000000111100011111111111111000111100011110001111111111100000000000001111
>  1111111111111111111111111110000000111100011111111111111000111100011110001111111111100000000000001111
>  0000000000000000000000001110000111111111100011111000000111111100000000001111000111100011111111111111
>  0000000000000000000000001110000111111111100001110000000111111100000000001110000111100011111111111111
>  0000000000000000000000001110000111111111100001110000000111111100000000001110000111100011111111111111
>  0000000000000000000000001110000111111111100001110000000111111100000000001110000111100011111111111111
>  0001111111111111111100001111111000111111100001110001111000111111100000001111111111100000001111110000
>  0001111111111111111100001111111000111111100001110001111000111111100000001111111111100000001111110000
>  0001111111111111111100001111111000111111100001110001111000111111100000001111111111100000001111110000
>  0001111111111111111100001111111000111111100001110001111000111111100000001111111111100000001111110000
>  0001111000000000011100001110000000111111100000001111111111000000011110000000000000000011110000001111
>  0001111000000000011100001110000000111111100000001111111111000000011110000000000000000011110000001111
>  0001111000000000011100001110000000111111100000001111111111000000001110000000000000000011110000001111
>  0001111000000000011100001110000000111100000001111111111000111100000001110001111111111100001111110000
>  0001111000000000011100001110000000111100000001111111111000111100000001110001111111111100001111110000
>  0001111000000000011100001110000000111100000001111111111000111100000001110001111111111100001111110000
>  0001111000000000011100001110000000011100000011111111111000111100000011110000111111111000001111110000
>  0001111000000000011100001110000000000011111111111110000000111100011111110000000000000000001110001111
>  0001111000000000011100001110000000000011111111111110000000111100011111110000000000000000001110001111
>  0001111000000000011100001110000000000011111111111110000000111100011111110000000000000000011110001111
>  0001111111111111111100001110000000111111100001111110000000111100011110000001111111100011111110001111
>  0001111111111111111100001110000000111111100001111110000000111100011110000001111111100011111110001111
>  0001111111111111111100001110000000111111100001111110000000111100011110000001111111100011111110001111
>  0000000000000000000000001110000000111111100000000000000111000011100001110001111111100011110001111111
>  0000000000000000000000001110000000111111100000000000000111000011100001110001111111100011110001111111
>  0000000000000000000000001110000000111111100000000000000111000011100001110001111111100011110001111111
>  0000000000000000000000001110000000111111100000000000000111000011100001110001111111100011110001111111

If you...

> zoom out it's possible to notice that this is a QRCODE [image: bin]

So...

> using Excel you could just [image: qr]

Using a...

> QRcode reader you can read out the contents: "A riddle inside an enigma, a enigma inside a riddle"

And that's it.

> And yeah, I noticed that I misspelled right there between those `enigma`

Sorry if I made this too hard and/or confusing, was just my first try. :(

I expect to get better at this to give you guys some puzzles to enjoy in the future.

Comment: Most of it seems fine to me - if I had gotten to the "binary with 2s and 3s" step, I certainly would've solved it (and enjoyed it!). But that first step was a massive hurdle - AES encryption isn't very well-known here.

Comment: Anyway, welcome to Puzzling! I hope to see more from you. c:

Comment: Thank you, I'll work on another one more interesting, simple and subtle :D (And yeah, it really went nuts when added AES encryption, just thought it would be too easy to just give the binary or compressed data)

Comment: Nice "rabbit-hole", however you could leave some "story" hints (Like: I worked in Advanced Energy Something group in 7th floor and blablabla). You are like me with first puzzle - I had too much believe in people :) Just place random hints around and people will figure that out if they wanted.